# Google Maps just showing on my device

Tags: android, google-maps

I have developed an android app for my company, where I have introduced a map in a fragment.

The app works fine on my phone, but when providing this app to other fellow workers, in their phones the map is not showing, it appears the focus buttons and the Google logo, but that's it, no map.

**layout**

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

**manifest**

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<!-- The following two permissions are not required to use
    Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended. -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

...

<meta-data 
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="AIzaSyArrfA3PQ9kVcwucUGZCoc9yMUC9wc2g_4"/>
```

**Fragment**

```
/*Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment*/
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

Comment: You are probably using a debug key to show the maps, that is why you see it only in your device.

Comment: Are you giving them an apk file or let them build their own app? If the latter - the problem is described by @zozelfelfo

Comment: @zozelfelfo I'm checking in the Google console but i'm not sure of it. I have a tought too that it could be because the API key, but I think I'm using a normal one. This is what says there 'Key for Android applications'

Comment: @Michal K I build the app and export to an apk which I send to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a debug key problem.
you must use a release key.
With version 2 API's you can use the same key for release and debug. In your google api's console edit your allowed android apps and on each line put your debug/release key, and then your app name. You can use multiple lines, then it will work with both keys.

Comment: Could you extend a bit your answer? I'm checking the console but I don't find any reference to debug/release. In credentials I have just a key for Android applications, and the one for browser applications which I think is created atuomatically.

Comment: Ok, solved now. As @zozoelfelfo has told you, you should improve one answer instead of posting a new one. I'll accept this one, but you should consider deleting the other one.

Answer (score 0):

In Google Developer API Console

1. Click on Create New Android key...
2. In cmd.exe/Terminal: keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
3. Password: android
4. Now enter SHA1 key;package name for debug and   press enter
5. Enter SHA1 key;package name for release
6. Click on Create

Now use this API key your project

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/common_map_api_key"/>
```

Comment: why didnt you improve your answer instead of using a new one?